# Query DNS for multiple domains at once

Tags: nameserver, query

I have recently moved servers and want to query all of the accounts domains on the new server to check that they are all resolving to the correct NS.

I am currently using http://www.whatsmydns.net/#NS which is great.

However, it's rather a slow process for 100 domains!

Can anyone recommend any tool available?

Thanks

Comment: I needed the exact same thing so I built an interface which allows me to test my list of domains against both the new and old name servers and compare the difference in a table - http://www.matraex.com/nameserver-compare.php

Answer (score 3):

Use `dig` from the command line, or `nslookup` if you're on windows. Either of these would be trivial to script and get the data you need.

Comment: dig or nslookup still send a separate query for each domain. Can we compact all domains (or a couple domains) in just ONE DNS query instead of sending multiple queries separately?

Answer (score 2):

simple bash script to loop and output just the IP address of each domain:

```sh
mydomains=(
domain1
domain2
domain3
)

for i in "${mydomains[@]}"; do dig $i +short; done
```

Comment: Can we compact all domains (or a couple domains) in just *ONE* DNS query instead of sending multiple queries separately like this?

Answer (score 1):

Are they external domains or internal domains? In any case, you can run something like:

I will use serverfault.com as my example domain here.

To resolve the hostname: www.serverfault.com

```
dig @4.2.2.2 www.serverfault.com +short
```

To find out the NS for your domain, serverfault.com

```
dig serverfault.com ns
```

To find the authoratative name servers for your domain:

```
dig serverfault.com +nssearch
```

If you have 100 external domains, you can write a for look and run as a shell scripts. Make sure all zones you are trying to query are on a separate lines. If you know your DNS or want to include in the dig command you can do so as: `dig @4.2.2.2 $zone +short`

In the above command 4.2.2.2 was my DNS Server.

```
#!/bin/bash
while read zone; do dig $zone +short; done <myzones.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a PowerShell script that could work.

http://cloud.kemta.net/2012/11/powershell-checking-multiple-dns-records-for-multiple-domains/

I also like to use http://www.intodns.com for DNS work.  Nice clean interface.  However you would still need to enter them one at a time.

Answer (score 0):

You will be able to lookup multiple DNS records using this tool I wrote

http://www.matraex.com/quick-domain-research.php

It lists out the domainname, A records if any for @ and www, MX and NS records for the domain,  it lists the Email addresses for the WHOIS contacts,  as well as the NS Records on the Whois and puts them in a table for multiple domains.

I have used it to quickly address many DNS related issues.